# QGIS, GDAL Georeferencer missing?

Tags: qgis, installation, georeferencing, fedora

I've just installed QGIS 2.8 on the new Fedora 22 (64) that came out some days ago. Awkwardly, I can't find the GDAL Georeferencer that, to my knowledge, is supposed to come with every installation. Searching for it in the  Plugin Manager doesn't give any results so I'm unable to activate it thereby adding it to the `Raster` menu. Re-installing it all is no good either.
Any idea what might be the cause for this? Just two days ago, everything worked perfectly fine (2.8 running on Fedora 21). Or is it just me being lost in the woods?

---

Recently, I downgraded back to Fedora 21 (less buggy at the moment) but am now facing the exact same problem. Is the Georeferencer included somewhere else by now?

[image: Missing Georeferencer]

Comment: A late answer for fedora 24: The georeferencer is included in the neteler rpm builds, but for some reason deactivated. Make sure to have qgis-python installed.

Comment: Georeferencer based on GDAL, do you have GDAL and GDAL utilities (gdal_translate and gdal_warp)?